# How to include other jar module's system scope jar

Tags: maven, jar, multi-module

I have created a multiple module project with Maven,
module common is a jar module and it has some system scope jars,
module api is a web war module and it depends on module common,
I execute mvn package,but module api can't include the system scope jars into WEB-INF/lib,how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Please don't use `system` scope dependency, when you use it you will be surprised by some another problem in the future.

`system` dependency like `provided` is not **transitive**, so this dependency will not be included in `WEB_INF/libs`

When you use system dependency, you have to **manualy** supply those artifacts in each system where you build or run project.

Comment: Thanks.I have solved it by using maven-install-plugin.Delete system scope and using maven-install-plugin to upload the jars to local repository, finally mvn package can include the jars by using local repository